# Avoiding boundary with a preceding word in regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex that detects something called a `PO Number` that is PO Number followed by some characters that may or may not be digits but certainly contains a digit. It can also have spaces.

You can see the [link](http://regexr.com/3buv3) to find the problem.

**Pattern:**

```
((P\s*o\s*(\#|Number|No|\.)*\s*([:=\-\'\s\.])?\s*(\d*\s?([A-Z\-\/]*\s?\d+)+[A-Z\-]*)))
```

The problem arises when there is something like:

`Case 3.  Ship on 123`

Here p is followed by o and the following conditions are good for match. But I needed to check the condition preceding 'p' that is 'shi'p.

Clearly, I needed to implement something to avoid p preceded by a plain word [A-Z]+ but allow p if its preceded by a space or a digit. Following conditions should pass.

`Case 1.  YO#11111PO#2015 S53-55A`

`Case 2.  YO#12345_PO#234 S34-34A`

I tried using word boundary `\b` but that causes case 1 and 2 to fail. Is there another way.

Comment: Add `(?:^|[^a-z])` in the pattern just before `P`.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Can you put this as answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: You should include the pattern in your question as well. Besides, there already is a similar answer below. :)

Comment: @hjpotter92 Done. Why did you add the `^|` in `(?:^|[^a-z])`. As `(?:[^a-z])` also seems to work fine?

Comment: In case the string starts with `PO`

Comment: Yeah! Thats more correct than Tom Winch's answer I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Try preceding your regexp with `(?:[^a-z])`

This is a non-capturing group so when you interpret your groups it won't appear in the list.